# Retrieve buffer with multiple overlapped I/O requests

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, winsock, iocp

There is something I'd like to know about overlapped I/O under windows, both with and without I/O completion ports.
I know in advance how many packets I will be receiving after using WSASend().

So I'd like to do that

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   WSARecv(sock, &buffer_array[i], 1, NULL, 0, &overlapped, completion_routine);
```

My problem is : how can I know which buffer has been filled upon notification the buffer has been filled? I mean, without guessing by the order of the calls (buffer[0], buffer[1], buffer[2], etc.).

I would find an alternative solution that gives me the buffer pointer at the time of the notification much more clean for example, and more easily changeable/adaptable as the design of my application evolves.

Thanks.

Comment: That makes little sense, use WSARecvFrom() instead.

Comment: @Hans Passant WSARecvFrom() isnt anything faster or more useful, on the contrary its kind of counter productive with IOCP to have a thread dedicated to receiving packets from one address in particular.

Answer (score 2):

Right now you are starting `n` concurrent receive operations. Instead, start them one after the other. Start the next one when the previous one has completed.

Comment: Exactly I want to fill n buffers. I understand what you mean, my application needs to be extremely latency oriented (more than you think). Since I process each packet after a receive, it adds overhead to use WSARecv() one after the other if for example I received X packets simultaneously. That's what I am doing at the moment and my question is oriented toward being able to change that behavior.

Comment: Are you using UDP? Then all packets are independent and unordered. It should not matter what order you receive the packets in.

Comment: Its UDP yes, but UDP used for network diagnosis. Among the parameters I'm recolting, there is latency. So if you get me, it's bothersome to have your readings biased by overhead, hence why I'm trying to lower it as much as possible. With IOCP it's not really problematic, but if I use overlapped I/O without IOCP (only 1 receive thread), it's more efficient to get the buffers filled before processing the packets. It's microoptimization yes, but multiply it by 1000 and you have some gains.

Comment: To simplify, lets stay in the frame of the question. Basically what I'm trying to know is if the API permits it... or not at all.

Comment: You need to use a different overlapped structure for each call. AFAIK that is a requirement in any case. The code is broken in that regard even if you did not care about order. Also note, that you must deal with lost packets. Probably, you need to cancel those IOs because they will continue to hang around and "capture" future packets.

Answer (score 0):

When using a completion routine, the hEvent field in the OVERLAPPED block is unused and can be used to pass context info into the completion routine.  Typically, this would be a pointer to a buffer class instance or an index to an array of buffer instances.  Often, the OVL block would be a struct member of the instance since you need a separate OVL per call.